# Macro don't work

Tags: c++, macros

```
#define SAFE_RELEASE(ptr) {if((ptr)){(ptr)->Release(); (prt)=nullptr;}}
```

This is a macro from one game programming book; In VS2012 when I call this macro, there is a compilation error:

```
SAFE_RELEASE(device3D);
SAFE_RELEASE(direct3D);
```

Error is " 'ptr': undeclared identifier ".

Comment: DId you mean `(ptr)=nullptr;` instead of `(prt)=nullptr;`

Comment: posting a question here is easier than reading one line code :p

Comment: Yes, please sorry me for so noobish questions((.

Comment: I would highly suggest looking at one of the many COM Smart Pointer libraries such as the [ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx), [WRL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244983.aspx) or even the compiler supported [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo in your macro

```
(prt)=nullptr;
```

should be

```
(ptr)=nullptr;
```

(Note that this wouldn't explain the error message you posted.  I'm assuming there is a typo in it as well!)

Comment: That's what I thought too. It should be `Error is " 'prt': undeclared identifier ".`

Comment: I'm not going to -1 for an attempt to answer an unanswerable question.

Comment: @DieterLücking I thought showing the typo was all the explanation that was required.  What else would you have expected to see?